# Batch Get specific PID

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, pid

I am trying to kill a vbscript from Batch, and I got this so far:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('tasklist^|find /i "wscript.exe"') do (set pid=%%a)
```

That gets *a* wscript PID, so I guess if there is more than one running wscript it will just take a random? I do not really know about that. But I want to get the PID of a **specific** process/task, this one to be exact:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN9BO.png
Is there a way of getting the PID from the Commandline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wmic can filter the processes by command line:

```
@echo off


for /f  "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('
    wmic process where "name='wscript.exe' and commandline like '%%5MinutesMSG%%'" get ProcessID /format:value
') do (
    for /f  "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%%a") do (
        set "%%#"
    )
)

echo %processid%
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thank you! Adding a taskkill /f /pid %processid% to that saved my day - thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this vbscript : **Wscript_Killer_Selector.vbs**

```
Option Explicit
Dim Titre,Copyright,fso,ws,NomFichierLog,temp,PathNomFichierLog,OutPut,Count,strComputer
If AppPrevInstance() Then 
    MsgBox "Il y a une instance déjà en cours" & VbCrLF & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,"Il y a une instance déjà en cours"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else 
Copyright = "[© Hackoo © 2015 ]"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = CreateObject( "Wscript.Shell" )
NomFichierLog="Killed Process.txt"
temp = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%temp%")
PathNomFichierLog = temp & "\" & NomFichierLog
Set OutPut = fso.CreateTextFile(temp & "\" & NomFichierLog,1)
strComputer = "."
    Call Find("wscript.exe")
    Call Explorer(PathNomFichierLog)
End If
'***************************************************************************************************
Function Explorer(File)
    Dim ws
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    ws.run "Explorer "& File & "\",1,True
end Function
'***************************************************************************************************
Sub Find(MyProcess)
    Dim colItems,objItem,Processus,Question
    Titre = " Processus "& DblQuote(MyProcess) &" en cours d'exécution "
    Set colItems = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process " _
    & "Where Name like '%"& MyProcess &"%' AND NOT commandline like " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "",,48)
    Count = 0 
    For Each objItem in colItems
        Count= Count + 1
        'Processus = Mid(objItem.CommandLine,InStr(objItem.CommandLine,""" """) + 2) 'Extraction du chemin du script en ligne de commande
        Processus = objItem.CommandLine 'Replace(Processus,chr(34),"")
        Question = MsgBox ("Voulez-vous arrêter ce script : " & DblQuote(Processus) & " ?" ,VBYesNO+VbQuestion,Titre+Copyright)
        If Question = VbYes then
            objItem.Terminate(0)'Tuer ce processus
            OutPut.WriteLine Processus
        else
            Count= Count - 1 'décrementer le compteur de -1
        End if
    Next
OutPut.WriteLine String(100,"*")
OutPut.WriteLine count & Titre & "ont été arrêtés"
OutPut.WriteLine String(100,"*") & VbCrLF 
End Sub
'**************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function   
'**************************************************************************
Sub Pause(Minutes)    
    Wscript.Sleep(Minutes*1000*60)    
End Sub   
'**************************************************************************
Function StripProcPath(ProcessPath)   
    Dim arrStr : arrStr = Split(ProcessPath, "\")   
    StripProcPath = arrStr(UBound(arrStr))   
End Function   
'**************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'**************************************************************************
```